# Install robot framework on python3 not python2

Tags: python, installation, robotframework

I have python3 pre-installed in fedora, somehow python2 was installed later. After using

```
pip install robotframework
```

robot was installed successfully, but it was installed in python 2.7/site-packages.

Is there any way to install and use it in python3? Or, is it possible to uninstall python2, and re-install robot framework on python3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Try this command It may help you in my case it works!

```
pip3 install robotframework
```

If you are using proxy server then use this command

```
pip3 --proxy <host>:<port> install robotframework
```

Example

```
pip3 --proxy 12.3.105.200:8080 install robotframework
```

And you can uninstall pre-installed by using this

```
pip uninstall robotframework
```

Comment: Thanks. I simply remove python2, then do a pip install, and it works.

Comment: Ya! It's also a better option to use virtual env in such cases as mentioned in @wonton's answer .

Answer (score 2):

You can use below commands to install robot framework for specific python version if you had multiple python version installed,

```
python -m pip install robotframework   #python 2
python3 -m pip install robotframework  #python 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Robotframework has versions for both python 2 and 3, so this is definitely an issue of managing your python environment.

To avoid issues like this in the future, I strongly urge you to use [virtual environments](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

In a nutshell, you can solve this problem by doing

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install robotframework
```